# Possible Jenkins Perform Maven Release distance?

Tags: web-services, maven, jenkins, release, jenkins-workflow

I use Jenkins and i try to work with it with REST api webservices on C#,
I can use buildWithParameters but my question is simple :

How it is possible to use Perform Maven Release (with parameters) at distance ?

Thx!